# How can i create a ModalPopupExtender control dynamically from a server control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-server-controls, servercontrols

I have a composite server control that does quiet a number of things; one of which is to display a ModalPopup OnClick of a dynamically generated HtmlAnchor control.

I need to create this ModalPopupExtender control dynamically in my server control and trigger it from within.

I have been able to create it and trigger it from a button created at design time but not at runtime. This is as a result of the ID assign to the link is always not found by the ModalPopupExtender control.

I have tried assigning a static ID but no success. Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you have a code sample?  What do you mean by staticId?

Comment: Normally, i would use the ClientID property to get the ID of the control, but i hard coded it.

e.g: modalPopup.TargetControlID = 'ctl00_PageContents_drugBins_1';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. All i needed to do was recreate the HtmlAnchor control in the overridden CreateChildControls method on postback.

Thanks David for you concern.